# Configuration issues with sonarqube developer edition

Tags: .net, sonarqube

We are currently running a Sonarqube Developer Edition.
Version 9.4.0.54424

We configured sonarqube developer edition through github actions.

The issue that we are experiencing is we have 7 folders in our source code file and sonarqube is analyzing only one file and rest of the files are not being analysed, not sure if we have missed any thing related to configuration, could anyone please help us to analyse the code accurately.

[enter image description here][1]

Comment: Can you share about how the analysis is run? What are the settings & parameters?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SonarQubeAnalysisProperties  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sonarsource.com/msbuild/integration/2015/1">

  <Property Name="sonar.host.url">https://sonarqube.xxxxxx-xxxxx.xx/</Property>
  <Property Name="sonar.exclusions">./BuildScripts/**,./DatabaseMigrations/**</Property>
  <Property Name="sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths">**/*.trx</Property>
  <Property Name="sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths">**/coverage.opencover.xml</Property> 
</SonarQubeAnalysisProperties>

Comment: this is the  "SonarQube.Analysis.xml" file that is being used.                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                     
  we are using github actions to trigger the workflow.

Comment: Do you use something similar to this ?
https://medium.com/c-sharp-progarmming/github-sonarqube-workflow-net-280de7f02292

Do you provide as input the correct .sln file ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Cedric, we are using the same github actions workflow to trigger sonarqube when ever there is pull request raised.  adding our github actions workflow in my question.

Comment: Great!

Could be interesting to have the full analysis trace. 
Could you share it and run with the setting "sonar.verbose=true" ?

Comment: Could you please advise where do I add  : "sonar.verbose=true" ? in my file

Comment: Could you try:

<Property Name="sonar.verbose">true</Property>

Comment: Thank you Cedric, I am going to try that right away.

Comment: I have tried with the below SonarQube.Analysis.xml file however there is no luck                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<SonarQubeAnalysisProperties  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sonarsource.com/msbuild/integration/2015/1">
 <Property Name="sonar.host.url"></Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.exclusions">./BuildScripts/**,./DatabaseMigrations/**</Property>
        <Property Name="sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths">**/*.trx</Property>
 <Property Name="sonar.verbose">true</Property>

Comment: I have changed the yml fileas per the sonarqube documentation , still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: I have changed my yml file as per sonar documentation, still the issue is same :https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/github-integration/

Comment: I understand the root cause of the issue, the issue is with the properties file , not with the workflow, working on propertied file

Comment: Sorry if it didn't help.
Actually, would it be possible to have a full trace of the scan?
That might help :)

Comment: the issue is restricted only to .net microservice application, I am not able to find any help to resolve this from any one online. not sure how to resolve this. https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-build-is-not-successful-could-any-one-help-on-this/73460/7

Comment: Sorry to hear this. 
Indeed the SonarSource community seems to be the most relevant help for you.
Hope they'll provide you any support !

Comment: Thank you Cedric Teyton